# Spring data orderBy substring of String field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I would like to make a query to the database to return a list of persons, ordered by name starting from the second letter.

```
Bailey
Adam
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming JPA 2.0, you can do this using a custom JPQL query:

```
@Query("select p from Person p order by substring(p.name, 2)")
List<Person> findPersons();
```

Hibernate supports the [`SUBSTRING`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html/ch13.html#d5e2102) JPQL function. Quoting Hibernate documentation:

> **SUBSTRING**
>
> Extracts a portion of a string value.
>
> `substring( string_expression, numeric_expression [, numeric_expression] )`
>
> The second argument denotes the starting position. The third (optional) argument denotes the length.

Note that the first position of a String is 1. If the length is not specified, it defaults to the length of the rest of the String. This is specified in [JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf), paragraph 4.6.17.2.1.

Comment: It looks like it is not optional: java.sql.SQLException: The substring function requires 3 argument(s)

Comment: @Bouncer00 Which version of Hibernate are you using? Try with `@Query("select p from Person p order by substring(p.name, 2, length(p.name) - 1)")`

Answer (score 2):

See [full list of supported query keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords).
Probably you should use `ENDING_WITH`, `LIKE` or `REGEX`.

Example:

```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
            User findByNameEndingWith(String nameEndingWith);
    }

    findByNameEndingWith("dam"); //Will return you entity with name Adam
```

Comment: It's just an example. If he has strict requirements to find entities starting from second symbol, it'll be better use a REGEX. Unfortunately I have no Spring Data JPA project to try the Regex code, but the code will be much more cleaner than using Hibernate @Query.